# Excel countif where criteria references the range being counted?

Tags: excel, countif

I have an excel spreadsheet with three columns (C, D, E): R, G, B.

Each column will have a value in it ranging from 0 to 255. Each set of three values (each row) represents a colour. A shade of grey is identified by all three columns (for a given row) having the same value. There are 554 rows (not that this makes a difference to the solution).

Without adding extra columns, is there a way to use `countif()` to count the shades of grey in the range (C:E).

I have already tried a number of variations (based on solutions to different problems here on SE) - none of which work:

```
=COUNTIF(C:E,AND(C:C=D:D,D:D=E:E))

=COUNTIF(C:E,AND(OFFSET(C:E,0,0,1,1)=OFFSET(C:E,0,1,1,1),OFFSET(C:E,0,0,1,1)=OFFSET(C:E,0,2,1,1)))

=COUNTIF(C:E,AND(INDEX(C:C,ROW())=INDEX(D:D,ROW()),INDEX(D:D,ROW())=INDEX(E:E,ROW())))
```

I believe there has to be a solution - I just haven't stumbled on it yet. Any ideas would be appreciated. If `countif()` is the wrong function to use, then I am obviously open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C555=D2:D555)*(C2:C555=E2:E555))
```

`C2:C555=D2:D555` checks whether each cell in `C2:C555` is equal to the corresponding cell in `D2:D555` and returns an array of `TRUE` and/or `FALSE`.

`C2:C555=E2:E555` does the same thing, but with columns C and E.

Multiplication of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values give an array (another array) of 1s and 0s where only `TRUE*TRUE` gives 1.

`SUMPRODUCT` then sums each of the individual 1s and 0s. You can use `SUM` instead, but it would require array formula entry (i.e. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to work properly).

Comment: That is excellent. And, I do appreciate the explanation. Now I just have to figure out how I can avoid limiting the range (ie - c:c instead of c2:c555), but to all intents and purposes, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, I augmented the solution given by @Jerry to solve for the case of range unknown.

    =SUMPRODUCT((NOT(C:C=""))*(C:C=D:D)*(D:D=E:E))

Comment: @PeterAbolins Ah, yes, if you have blanks, they will also count as being 'same value across the columns'. The only issue with `SUMPRODUCT` is that it's quite the expensive function and can impede performance when you have a really large range.